MS Teams Meeting Crashes when Camera is turned on
We have been having a cascading problem where some users' Teams will freeze or crash when they turn on their Logitech camera for a meeting.  Each camera goes through a Lenovo Thunderbolt 4 docking station, and re-plugging the camera into its USB port does nothing.
One method that has worked for some users is to close Teams on their phone before joining their meeting.  Sometimes when you restart Teams after it crashes, it will prompt you to "Switch to this device" since it thinks you're still in the meeting on another device.
Other than closing Teams Mobile, we've applied updates to Logitune, updated drivers for the docks, cleared Teams cache, and uninstalled the "Computer Wide Installer." Problem ends up fixed for some with these steps, but not for others.
Has anyone else seen a similar problem lately?

Hi, Some docking need an firmware upgrade to work correctly, does you checked that path ?

Yes.  All relevant firmware and drivers for the dock are up-to-date.
